# Build JSON from JavaScript array recursively

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, recursion

I want to build a JSON object from an array returned from http request
my actual array look like:

```
[{
    Description: "Product"
    IsInstanciable: false
    IsMasked: false
    Name: "ProductBase"
    Subclasses: [{
      Description: "Product2"
      IsInstanciable: false
      IsMasked: false
      Name: "ProductBase2",
      Count: 5,
      Subclasses:[]
    },
    {
      Description: "Product3"
      IsInstanciable: false
      IsMasked: false
      Name: "ProductBase3",
      Count: 4,
      Subclasses:[],
    }]
},
{
    Description: "Product4"
    IsInstanciable: false
    IsMasked: false
    Name: "ProductBase4",
    Count: '...',
    Subclasses: [...]
}
```

I want to create a JSON object recursively from the array above. It will look like this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Product',
    Count: 9,
    children: [
      {name: 'Product2'},
      {name: 'Product3'},
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Product4',
    children: [
      {
        name: '...',
        Count: 'Sum of Count in all children by level'
        children: [
          {name: '...'},
          {name: '...'},
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

Here is my recursively function in typescript but it doesn't work as expected. How can I fix this?

```js
recursive(data, stack: TreeNode[]) {
    let elt: TreeNode = {name:'', children: []}
    if(data.Subclasses.length > 0) {
      elt.name = data.Description;
      data.Subclasses.forEach(element => {
        elt.children.push({name: element.Description});
        this.recursive(element, stack);
      });
    }else {
      elt.name = data.Description;
    }
    stack.push(elt);
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the map function together with the recursive function like this:

```
function MapObject(object) {
  if(!object || object.length < 0) return [];

  return object.map(obj => { return {
      name: obj.Description,
      children: MapObject(obj.Subclasses)
  }});
}
```

Follows a full work example:

```js
var example = [{
    Description: "Product",
    IsInstanciable: false,
    IsMasked: false,
    Name: "ProductBase",
    Subclasses: [{
      Description: "Product2",
      IsInstanciable: false,
      IsMasked: false,
      Name: "ProductBase2",
      Subclasses:[]
    },
    {
      Description: "Product3",
      IsInstanciable: false,
      IsMasked: false,
      Name: "ProductBase3",
      Subclasses:[]
    }]
},
{
    Description: "Product4",
    IsInstanciable: false,
    IsMasked: false,
    Name: "ProductBase4"
}]

function MapObject(object) {
  if(!object || object.length < 0) return [];
  
  return object.map(obj => { return {
      name: obj.Description,
      children: MapObject(obj.Subclasses)
  }});
}

console.log(MapObject(example));
```

Comment: Hi Ricardo, what if i want to add the sum of all count attributes by level ? Thank you

Comment: Can you put an example of the json?

Comment: I modified the json example in the question above

Answer (score 1):

I would break this down into a few separate functions with clear responsibilities:

```js
const sum = (ns) => 
  ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + Number (b), 0)

const getCount = (product) => 
  (product .Count || 0) + sum ((product .Subclasses || []) .map (getCount))

const extract = (product) => 
  ({
    name: product .Name,
    count: getCount (product),
    children: product .Subclasses .map (extract)
  })

const extractAll = (products) => 
  products .map (extract)

const products = [{"Description": "Product", "IsInstanciable": false, "IsMasked": false, "Name": "ProductBase", "Subclasses": [{"Count": 5, "Description": "Product2", "IsInstanciable": false, "IsMasked": false, "Name": "ProductBase2", "Subclasses": []}, {"Count": 4, "Description": "Product3", "IsInstanciable": false, "IsMasked": false, "Name": "ProductBase3", "Subclasses": []}]}, {"Count": 3, "Description": "Product4", "IsInstanciable": false, "IsMasked": false, "Name": "ProductBase4", "Subclasses": []}]

console .log (
  extractAll (products)
)
```

(Note that I changed the case of the output `count` property.  It just seemed more consistent with `name` and `children`.)

We recur through the object to get its `Count` property, and we recur separately to get the rest of the object.  While there might be a way to combine these, I would expect that the code would be significantly more complex.

Note that I assumed that all `Count` properties are actually numeric, although your example above includes a string.  If you do have values like `"3"`, then `getCount` will need to be a little more sophisticated.